# telegram deep linking start param is missing from start button

Tags: telegram

As per https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking

I have crafted a deep linking start URL

http://t.me/<my_bot>?start=token

When i enter this into my iOS safari browser it redirects to telegram, but the param is missing.
I see a start button, but when clicked it is just '/start' with no supplementary part where the  should be.

I'm expecting to receive

"start " as the message text on the webhook update.

Does anybody know why the param would be missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Sorry I don't have enough points to add a comment to your question, just wanted to tell you it doesn't work with Android too.</strike>

Ok, so it happens the mobile app (either Android or iOS) shows /start but actually sends `/start token` to the bot, where token is whatever you put after ?start=. Check your bot incomming messages.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28402748)

Comment: @Ruli please check my edited answer, which provides the answer to the question